# Ubuntu 15.04 - Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcuts

I saw a keyboard shortcuts list when I first installed Ubuntu 15.04.  How do I bring that up again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to press and hold the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (Windows key).

Comment: Definitely!  It is just making me wait a few mins before I can! :)

Comment: That key is broken on my laptop. How do I display this screen again if I don't have a super key?

Answer (score 0):

You have to press and hold <kbd>Super</kbd> key button.

There is one more way. This way will also help you to change shortcut keys.

**System Settings** -> **Keyboard**

In that select "shortcuts" tab at the top. There you can see a list of categorized shortcuts.