# Ubuntu 16.04, need help doing simple tasks lol

Tags: 16.04, copy, paste

I'm using an older computer so even if I did have Ubuntu 18.04 it'd run fairly slow (I know because I've tried lol) and Ubuntu 16.04 was the only one I could use on my laptop that'd run fast and connect to the WiFi, and my question is, I didn't pay attention to the Keyboard shortcuts, so, how do I copy and paste?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 15.04 - Keyboard shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615821/ubuntu-15-04-keyboard-shortcuts) The default copy/paste keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu 16.04 are the same keyboard shortcuts as in Windows - Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V.

Answer (score 1):

Various documentation exists in the Ubuntu Wiki that may be of assistance.  Much of it gets updated for later releases, thus some of it assumes you are using GNOME which is the default desktop for 18.04 LTS (where most will work in 16.04 LTS (Unity desktop), but a small number may not).

Useful Keyboard Shortcuts - https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en

Keyboard Shortcuts - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts

*the second [Keyboard Shortcuts] contains shortcuts that will all work in 16.04 LTS*

Also handy may be the Ubuntu Manual found at https://ubuntu-manual.org/ which you can download (*at no cost*). It currently still assumes 16.04 LTS (*too few people offered to help update it for 18.04 LTS*)

Comment: ps:  if GNOME is too slow for you on 18.04 LTS, a lighter DEsktop may be the fix. GNOME (and in fact Unity) is rather heavy (on resources, ram & cpu) thus using a lighter DE like XFCE (found in Xubuntu 18.04 LTS) or LXDE (Lubuntu 18.04 LTS) may work.

Answer (score 0):

Copying and pasting in Ubuntu can be done using the usual ctrl+c, ctrl+v shortcuts.
You can also right click on a file, text, etc. to get the options of cut, copy and paste.